# Normalidade e fragmentação da amostra

Tags: r

Estou com um problema em uma análise de `shapiro.test` no `R`. Quero analisar a normalidade de uma determinada variável `x`, mas quero fazer isso em amostras estratificadas que juntas correspondem a variável `y`.

```
set.seed(1)

df_1 <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(n = 30, mean = 10, sd = 1), 
  y = sample(x = 1:3, size = 30, replace = TRUE)
)
```

- É possível analisar `x` para cada grupo que está em `y`?

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar `tapply`:

```
set.seed(1)

df_1 <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(n = 30, mean = 10, sd = 1), 
  y = sample(x = 1:3, size = 30, replace = TRUE)
)

tapply(X = df_1$x, INDEX = df_1$y, FUN = shapiro.test)

#$`1`

#Shapiro-Wilk normality test

#data:  X[[i]]
#W = 0.98473, p-value = 0.9841


#$`2`

#Shapiro-Wilk normality test

#data:  X[[i]]
#W = 0.91978, p-value = 0.3552


#$`3`

#Shapiro-Wilk normality test

#data:  X[[i]]
#W = 0.90565, p-value = 0.2164
```

Answer (score 4):

É possível utilizar os pacotes `tidyverse` e `broom` e obter os resultados organizados em um data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

set.seed(1)

df_1 <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(n = 30, mean = 10, sd = 1), 
  y = sample(x = 1:3, size = 30, replace = TRUE)
)

df_1 %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  do(tidy(shapiro.test(.$x)))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#> # Groups:   y [3]
#>       y statistic p.value method                     
#>   <int>     <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>                      
#> 1     1     0.967   0.864 Shapiro-Wilk normality test
#> 2     2     0.928   0.361 Shapiro-Wilk normality test
#> 3     3     0.924   0.422 Shapiro-Wilk normality test
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Similar à [resposta do Marcus Nunes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/474521/117168), mas com `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df_1)

> df_1[, shapiro.test(x), by = y]
   y  statistic    p.value                      method data.name
1: 2 0.8751273 0.04955792 Shapiro-Wilk normality test         x
2: 1 0.9783130 0.95095668 Shapiro-Wilk normality test         x
3: 3 0.9572601 0.76925217 Shapiro-Wilk normality test         x
```